# Corona Enterprise: How to make zip folder in corona enterprise edition?

Tags: lua, compression, zip, static-libraries, coronasdk

Is there any static library present that can be integrated to corona enterprise for compressing a folder in document directory?

I am able to extract the zip file coming through using following link: http://www.keplerproject.org/luazip/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of libraries available to you: http://lua-users.org/wiki/CompressionAndArchiving

As you have the enterprise edition of Corona, you should be able to include these in your projects.